# How does scribd implement zooming?

Tags: javascript, zooming, scribd

Scribd's zooming functionality is very impressive. All the page content including images and text are zoomed proportionally when you click on their + and - buttons.

For example, try it on http://www.scribd.com/html5.

How do they do this? It doesn't seem to be as simple as controlling the browser zoom (although controlling browser zoom itself is not simple if not possible at all!)

A related question would be how they implement their 'full screen mode'. This question was [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279230/how-did-scribd-implement-their-fullscreen-mode) but that was two years ago when they were still using Flash.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that it might be a simple transformation of a [canvas](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#transformations) element, but looking at their source this does not appear to be the case.

Instead, it looks like the "Zoom In" function only affects the `img` tags on the page, so I'd say that probably they are just dynamically modifying the `width` and `height` attributes for those tags.  It's not a very sophisticated approach, and certainly doesn't rely on anything introduced in HTML5.

Edit:

Chrome's developer tools are excellent.  If you observe the DOM between zooms, it's easy to pinpoint how the effect is being implemented.  Here's what the markup looks like in the page's default state:

```
<div class="outer_page only_ie6_border" id="outer_page_1" 
     style="width: 516.8000000000015px; height: 400px; ">
      <div class="newpage" id="page1" 
           style="width: 902px; height: 697px; 
                 -webkit-transform: scale(0.5729490022172966); 
                 -webkit-transform-origin-x: 0%; 
                 -webkit-transform-origin-y: 0%; ">
      ...
</div>
</div>
```

...and after zooming out once:

```
 <div class="outer_page only_ie6_border" id="outer_page_1" 
     style="width: 646.0000000000018px; height: 500px; ">
      <div class="newpage" id="page1" 
           style="width: 902px; height: 697px; 
                 -webkit-transform: scale(0.7161862527716206); 
                 -webkit-transform-origin-x: 0%; 
                 -webkit-transform-origin-y: 0%; ">
      ...
</div>
</div>
```

...and after zooming out again:

```
<div class="outer_page only_ie6_border" id="outer_page_1" 
     style="width: 807.5000000000023px; height: 624px; ">
      <div class="newpage" id="page1" 
           style="width: 902px; height: 697px; 
                 -webkit-transform: scale(0.8952328159645258); 
                 -webkit-transform-origin-x: 0%; 
                 -webkit-transform-origin-y: 0%; ">
      ...
</div>
</div>
```

So it appears that they have implemented their zoom effect by doing two things:

1. Increasing the `width` and `height` of the container div.
2. Using the [webkit-transform](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/) CSS property to scale the contents up or down as needed.

Comment: It's not just images though, but also text that's scaled perfectly proportionally.

Comment: I don't think it's as simple as modifying the img width and heights. Not only is text scaled, but the relative position of text to images is maintained.

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize that the text was actually being floated on top of the image, I thought the text was simply part of the image itself.

Comment: And in any case, I've updated my answer with some additional details.